# Write a password as a secret in php

Tags: php, function, passwords

I have an admin panel, and I have a table in the panel that lists the usernames and passwords of the users.

Because passwords are encrypted with MD5, there is no objection to be listed, but you think you have a table in screen of you and you don't understand what a column of the table is, 32 characters of mixed string.

So I want to convert this column password char. For example;

```
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 = ********************************
```

I tried;

```
$str="hide me";
$strarr=str_split($str);
foreach($strarr as $char){
    $str=str_replace($char,'*',$str);
}
echo $str;
```

Is there a shorter method?

Comment: *encrypted with MD5* probably isn't as accurate or as bullet proof as you think. More generally, why show the passwords at all?

Comment: Yeah, md5 is neither encryption, nor secure.

Comment: Why show the value at all, if it's meaningless?

Comment: @iainn  My goal is to show the password as " * ". And next to the "Change password" button to provide password control with the button.
I said something wrong?

Comment: Hint: MD5 hashes all have the same length. The result what you want will always be 32 asterisks…

Comment: @aliitascan No, there's nothing wrong with your question. I just don't see the benefit in showing the same 32-character string of asterisks next to every username, instead of just not having a password column at all.

Comment: @deceze I know, but I have to show my password secret way. Username: "Jack" Password: "hey here password" instead I want to do Password: " ***** ". It is much better if you help my question instead of criticizing what I want to do. Like Nuwan did.

Comment: I'm trying to point you to a very very simple solution: `echo '********************************';`. Or to not output anything at all, because what's the point?

Comment: @iainn There is a proverb in my country. "Each man different way of eating yogurt." Mean "Everybody cherishes his own way of doing things". Why do you give minus points if my question isn't wrong? Anyway, others peoples helped.

Comment: @deceze I never thought that. I think I've written a lot of code, my head stopped.Lol. Why didn't you tell me before? :((
Okay, I'm going. But please think that I might have missed something so simple before minus points it. Lol

How could I not think that :(

Comment: @aliitascan I didn't down-vote your question, and if you start assuming that people who are asking you for clarification aren't trying to help you then you're going to have an interesting time here. My point was identical to deceze's, but it seems like you've figured it out by now anyway.

Comment: @iainn Yeah. I'm sorry. My head is too full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
$str="hide me";
echo str_repeat('*',strlen($str));
```

PS: MD5 is no longer considered secure enough for password.Use BCRYPT instead.[refer here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this. But people don't understand and give a score minus points.